# Spring data mongodb query on subdocument list using querydsl

Tags: spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I am using `QueryDSl` to dynamiclly query the documents.
I have Document like

```
Transaction {
  TxnId
  List ExceptionList [ {excpId, fieldName="ABC"} , {excpId, fieldName="XYZ"}]

  .....
}
```

Now I would like to search/sort the transactions based on `Transaction.ExceptionList.fieldName`

How can I do it using `QueryDSL-Spring-Data`(Mongo repositories) ?